# Display last logged in details using Devise in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise

I have a Rails 3 application and it's using Devise for the authentication.

I would like to display the date and time each user last logged in within the administration table of users.

I have based the application on the following application:

```
https://github.com/dannymcc/rails3-base
```

I have read through the Devise GitHub wiki and notice that it mentions that user events are trackable, but I can't find any information regarding accessing the information etc.

Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Danny

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) documentation outlines the trackable module which will do what you want.  In your user model, include the `:trackable` module like so:

```
  devise :database_authenticatable, 
      ...
      :trackable
```

And make sure your database has the right fields.  Not sure how do this if you already have a user table, but adding fields with the right names and types should do the trick.  My migration to create my users table looks like so:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email

      t.database_authenticatable :null => false
      t.recoverable
      t.rememberable
      t.trackable

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :users
  end
end
```

The `t.trackable` will add the correct fields.  In my user model, they're as follows:

```
sign_in_count: integer, 
current_sign_in_at: timestamp, 
last_sign_in_at: timestamp, 
current_sign_in_ip: string, 
last_sign_in_ip: string
```

Then you can just do `user.last_sign_in_at` and check the [strftime](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time.html#M000392) documentation on how to output the time in the format you want.

Answer (score 2):

## Devise 2.0 or later (currently 4.0)

Devise 2.0 no longer includes helpers for your migrations. It means that you can no longer use the migration shorthand `t.trackable`. Instead, you need to list the database fields explicitly.

Step by step, it goes like this.

1. Create a new migration file with:

```bash
rails generate migration AddDeviseTrackableColumnsToUsers
```

2. Edit your newly create file to include the following:

```rb
class AddDeviseTrackableColumnsToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    add_column :users, :sign_in_count, :integer, default: 0, null: false
    add_column :users, :current_sign_in_at, :datetime
    add_column :users, :last_sign_in_at, :datetime
    add_column :users, :current_sign_in_ip, :string
    add_column :users, :last_sign_in_ip, :string
  end
end
```

3. Run your migration:

```bash
rails db:migrate
```

4. Finally, update your User model to activate trackable:

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :trackable
end
```

Now you should be able to use `user.last_sign_in_at` without a problem

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `user.last_sign_in_at` use `current_user.sign_in_at` as you want the last sign in details of user logged in.