# Determine if a user has ever logged in or made an account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, user-experience

For UX sake, I have sign in and sign up forms on the same page.

However, I'd like to show the sign in page to people who are known to have ever logged in, and the sign up page to users who have never been known to log in.

It seems like something you could do with session and cookies, but it's not clear to me where I would place this code.

(I'm using Devise, rails 3 and mongoid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thankfully, Devise has thought of this for you :)

```
user.last_sign_in_ip
```

This requires the use of :trackable, which is very well detailed here:

[Display last logged in details using Devise in Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091169/display-last-logged-in-details-using-devise-in-rails-3)

If the value is nil, then the user has never signed in.  I think you know where to go from there.

Hope that helps!

-- Adding more detail for clarity

If you can't find the current user's IP, then they have not logged in.  So a search for

```
User.where :last_sign_in_ip => {current IP}
```

Should do you.  You don't even need to know which user, just that one exists.

Now, like you said, you can also use cookies, etc.  The logic would work the same way, though; you just get a bit of free lunch here from Devise.