# The first time a user logs in per day he/she should receive points for it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have a method which gives a score to the user if the user logs in once a day. How to determine the user entered into the system once a day? I am using devise authentication system.

```
::Gamification::RewardUserForLoggingJob.perform_later(user)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using devise, you should first include the `:trackable` symbol to your user model. The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091169/display-last-logged-in-details-using-devise-in-rails-3) should tell you how your user model and table should look like.
`:trackable` will add following information:

```
sign_in_count       # Increased every time a sign in is made (by form, openid, oauth)
current_sign_in_at  # A timestamp updated when the user signs in
last_sign_in_at     # Holds the timestamp of the previous sign in
current_sign_in_ip  # The remote ip updated when the user sign in
last_sign_in_ip     # Holds the remote ip of the previous sign in
```

Then, you need a method in your user model where you check if the users last log in was not today:

```
# models/user.rb
def daily_reward
  if self.last_sign_in_at.yday != Time.zone.now.yday
    # give your points here
  end
end

# controllers/sessions_controller.rb
def create
  user = #YourUserQuery
  if user and user.authenticate(params[:password])
    user.daily_reward
    # ...
  end
end
```